# Interpolation hitches caused by Quake-like client-server design

Tags: networking, client-server, interpolation, quake3

I'm building a very small multiplayer shooter game. I'm facing a problem related to interpolation. In order to explain the problem I have to give an overview of the client-server design of my game (it's very similar to Quake 3's).

This is the heart of the server:

```
// Runs 60 times per second
function tick() {
  // Each user command is keys pressed + view angle of the player
  let userCommands = readUserCommandsFromNetwork();

  for (let command of userCommands) {
    // Each user command results in 16ms of simulation for the player that created it
    movePlayer(command);
  }
  
  // We send game state updates 20 times per second (every 50 ms)
  if (isTimeForSnapshot()) {
    sendGameStateSnapshotToClients();
  }
}
```

This is what the client does:

```
let simulationTimeMs = 0.0;
let lastTimeMs = Date.now();

// Usual game loop where physics and rendering are separated. 
// Simulation happens in chunks of 1/60th of a second and we render as many frames as possible
function gameLoop() {
  let currentTimeMs = Date.now();
  let deltaTime     = currentTimeMs - lastTimeMs;
  let lastTimeMs    = currentTimeMs;
  simulationTimeMs += deltaTime;

  readGameStateSnapshotsFromNetwork(); // Read game state updates from server
  let inputs = readInputsFromKeyboardAndMouse();

  if (simulationTimeMs >= 1000/60) {
    movePlayer(inputs);
    reconcilePlayerPositionWithLatestGameStateFromServer();
    sendUserCommandToServer(inputs);
    simulationTimeSeconds -= 1000/60;
  }

  let interpolatedPlayers = interpolateOtherPlayers();

  renderCurrentState(interpolatedPlayers);
}
```

The design from above works really well for client-side prediction and reconciliation. Since each 16ms chunk of simulation that happens on the client is replicated on the server there's usually no disagreement between the predicted position and the authoritative position from the server.

The problem with the entity interpolation is that due to the usual weirdness of a network the server will process a variable number of user commands before sending the clients a game state snapshot. Let me explain this in steps:

- Player A and player B are connected to my server. They are both holding down the 'W' key to move forward. They each send one userCommand packet to the server every 16ms
- On tick X the server reads the userCommands from the network and simulates them
- On this particular tick the server processes 3 userCommands from player A and only 2 from player B (one userCommand from player B is still in flight). This effectively means that player A had 48 ms of simulation time on the server while player B only had 32 ms
- The server packs up the new positions of the players in a snapshot and sends that snapshot to the clients

Then what my client will do is linearly interpolate between this new snapshot that it has received and the snapshot that came right before it. The problem with this is that since player A had 48 ms of simulation they will appear to move faster than player B. Why? Because my interpolation code does not know anything about how many commands were simulated for each player. It simply uses the difference in time between the snapshots to calculate the interpolation factor and linearly interpolates between two positions:

```
oldSnapshot = {
  serverTime: 100ms,
  players: {
    A: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    B: { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
}

newSnapshot = {
  serverTime: 150ms,
  players: {
    A: { x: 30, y: 0 },
    B: { x: 20, y: 0 }
  }
}

// interpolate 100 ms in the past. Say client.currentTime is 230 ms
interpTime = client.currentTime - 100 ms =  230 - 100 = 130 ms

interpFactor = (130 ms - oldSnapshot.serverTime) / (newSnapshot.serverTime - oldSnapshot.serverTime) = 30 / 50 = 0.6

playerAInterpolatedX = (30 - 0) * 0.6 = 18
playerBInterpolatedX = (20 - 0) * 0.6 = 12
```

This produces very annoying visual hitches where you see a player suddenly speed up from one frame to another and it doesn't reflect the reality of what happened. Player A never moved faster than player B.

I have read Quake 3's source code but I haven't been able to figure out how they get around this problem (I'm pretty sure they are dealing with this somewhere). Is there an established solution for this that I haven't run into? Any suggestions on how to make sure interpolation accounts for the variability in simulation time between snapshots?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: You might find https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization useful.

Comment: I have read that article probably 15 times now. The ideas presented are very clear, but it falls short on implementation details. I don't think it explains how to handle the issue I discuss above.

Comment: That seems correct to me. Player A *did* move faster in that tick. And Player B's screen shows them moving faster. What is the problem, exactly? Player B's screen also showed them not moving at all, for the one command that was delayed.

Comment: As part of the packet data, you could include the time at which the packet was sent and have the server take that into consideration. If it arrives late, you could add more to it.